# Nextjs using _document with head tag on each page

Tags: html, next.js, head

I am using Next.js with typescript for my web site and all the components that should be in `<head>` is at `<body>`. 
I am using `_document.tsx` for google fonts and some other scripts. 
`pages/_document.tsx`

```js
import Document, { DocumentContext, Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';

class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx: DocumentContext) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);

    return initialProps;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head>
          <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
          <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
          <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet"
          />
          <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Gothic+A1:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet"
          />
          <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Parisienne&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet"
          />
          ...
        </Head>
        <body className="min-w-max">
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

export default MyDocument;
```

`pages/index.tsx`

```js
export default function Home() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Head>
          <title>title</title>
          ...
        </Head>

        ...
      </div>
    )
}
```

These are my `_document.tsx` and Home `index.tsx` and I get the result from DevTool element like down below.

[image: devtool element]

Like this image, eveything I set on Head both `_document.tsx` and `index.tsx` is in `<body>`. There are only some origin-trial meta tag that I didn't wrote in `<head>`. 
Because of this, `Warning: next-head-count is missing.` error is triggered and I followed the steps next.js suggested, but nothing changed. 
Any solution or idea for this?

Comment: Can't replicate the issue using the same exact `_document`. Could you provide a minimal reproducible example in codesandbox or similar?

Comment: @juliomalves I was checking my code to provide some more information and I just found the error and fixed it which I will post it below. Thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 1):

I made my `<Head>` tag as a component and used it in every page I got. Then I saw `<html lang="en">` in it. This was causing all my script tags inside of `<head>` position to `<body>`. After removing it, all works fine.

[Solution]: Do not use `<html>` tag inside of `<Head>`